# boundig variation from median

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Given a scalar random variable $X$, suppose that there are positive constants $c_{1}$ and  $c_{2}$ such that
$$\forall t\geq 0 : \,\,\,\,\,\,\ \mathbb P\{|X-\mathbb EX|\geq t\}\leq c_{1}e^{-c_{2}t^{2}}$$
A median $m_{X}$ is any number such that $\mathbb P \{ X \geq m_{X} \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb P \{ X \leq m_{X} \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$.  Show that for any median $m_{X}$, we have
$$\mathbb P \{ |X-m_{X}| \geq t \} \leq 4c_{1}e^{-\frac{1}{8}c_{2}t^{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $t=0$ in your first displayed inequality, note that necessarily $c_1\ge1$. Let then $u<EX$ be the root of the equation 
$$c_1e^{-c_2(EX-u)^2}=1/2. 
$$
Then 
$$P(X<u)=P(X-EX<u-EX)\le P(|X-EX|>EX-u)\le c_1e^{-c_2(EX-u)^2}=1/2, 
$$
so that $m:=m_X\ge u$. 
Take any real $t\ge0$. If 
$$EX-u\le t/2,$$
then 
$$P(X-m\ge t)=P(X-EX\ge m-EX+t)\le P(X-EX\ge u-EX+t)\le P(X-EX\ge t/2)\le
c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4}\le2c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4}. 
$$
On the other hand, if 
$$EX-u>t/2,$$
then 
$$P(X-m\ge t)\le1=2c_1e^{-c_2(EX-u)^2}\le2c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4}. 
$$
So, 
$$P(X-m\ge t)\le2c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4} 
$$
in any case. Similarly, $P(-(X-m)\ge t)\le2c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4}$. Thus, 
$$P(|X-m|\ge t)\le4c_1e^{-c_2t^2/4}. 
$$
This is a bit better than what you wanted (with $t^2/8$ in place of $t^2/4$).

Comment: Thank you.
The problem has a similar converse:
Show that whenever for a median $m_{X}$ we know
$$\mathbb P \{ |X-m_{X}| \geq t \} \leq c_{3}e^{-c_{4}t^{2}}$$
then
$$\mathbb P\{|X-\mathbb EX|\geq t\}\leq 2c_{3}e^{-\frac{1}{4}c_{4}t^{2}}.$$

Comment: Actually the existence of such a $u$ should be proved and it is clear that, it does not conclude from $c_{1} \geq1$ and we should prove $\ln (2c_{1}) >0$. It can be proved like this:
The problem in the case that $\mathbb EX=m_{X}$ is trivial. So we assume that $\mathbb EX \neq m_{X}$. Choose a real number $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon 
 < |\mathbb E-m_{X}|$.
Now we consider two cases:

Comment: 1. $\mathbb EX < m_{X}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq \mathbb P \{X \geq m_{X} \} \leq \mathbb P \{X-\mathbb EX \geq \epsilon \} \leq \mathbb P \{|X-\mathbb EX| \geq \epsilon \} \leq c_{1}e^{-c_{2}\epsilon^{2}}$$
So
$$2c_{1} \geq e^{c_{2}\epsilon^{2}} \implies \ln 2c_{1} > 0$$

Comment: 2. $\mathbb EX > m_{X}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq \mathbb P \{X \leq m_{X} \} \leq \mathbb P \{-X+\mathbb EX \geq \epsilon \} \leq \mathbb P \{|X-\mathbb EX| \geq \epsilon \} \leq c_{1}e^{-c_{2}\epsilon^{2}}$$
So
$$2c_{1} \geq e^{c_{2}\epsilon^{2}} \implies \ln 2c_{1} > 0$$

Comment: @Meysam : That the root $u$ exists (and is unique) is trivial. Indeed, this unique root $u$ equals $EX-\sqrt{\ln(2c_1)/c_2}$. Note also that $\ln(2c_1)\ge\ln2>0$.